# In windows service, how to get the service start time and service end time?

Tags: .net

In windows service, how to get the service start time and service end time?

Comment: Are you writing the service, or is it a pre-existing one that you are trying to track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `System.Diagnostics.Process` class. In particular, the StartTime and ExitTime properties.

```
//System.Diagnostics.Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess(); 
System.Diagnostics.Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById(6684);
Console.WriteLine(p.StartTime);
//...
Console.WriteLine(p.ExitTime);
```

Note that you can only call for ExitTime on a process that has completed, and you need to get the handle to the process before it exits.

[msdn docs for Process class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to do this manually within the OnStart and OnStop/OnShutdown events.

You could also try and interrogate the windows log for some kind of history?